# Put objects into a map using java reflection. Why is it giving error "method 'put(String, Person)' in mapwrapper not found?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

Using javafxcollections, FXMLloader. I want to invoke put(String,Person) using reflection. After we're done with that, it'd be a plus to explore further why that error is there.
My (semi pseudo)code:

*
MethodInvoker.invokeIt(FXMLLoader.getnamespace(), "put", "personname", personObject, String.class, person2.getclasss())
*

The 2 class at the end are used in

*(Map)Loader.getNamespace().get class().getDeclaredMethod("put", String.class, person2.getclass)*

That up there, is what's giving the method not found exception.

Pointers: Fxcollections has a wrapper that makes observable map around the map used by the FXMLloader.

TIP: Had another problem almost similar but about constructor lacking in ObservableArraylist. (So reflection on *getclass().get constructor().newInstance()* wouldn't work because no constructor. Solved that by wrapping it in my wrapper which has constructor, takes empty ObservableArraylist as param, and some input and fills it, then I used that in the reflection API.

Something similar is the issue here and for the life of all kinds of Pies, my brain just won't accept a hacky quickfix, so I agree to get stuck on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface `Map` uses generics for key and value:

```
Interface Map<K,V>
```

For your example

```
Interface Map<String,Person2>
```

These generic classes are checked by the compiler.

During runtime all generic classes are changed to `Object`. This process is called type erasure.

Therefore the method `V put(K key, V value)` or  `Person2 put(String key, Person2 value)` changes to `Object put(Object key, Object value)`.

You have to call

```
(Map)Loader.getNamespace().get class().getDeclaredMethod("put", Object.class, Object.class)
```